# Trouble accessing HTML array input field values in Django server side

Tags: html, django

For below input fields, I have an add button that duplicates the following input field so I can add multiple values of attributes. Here, the attributes are "color", "gender", and "size.

```
<tr>
    {% for att in attribute_set %}
        <td><input name="{{ att }}[]" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ att|title }}"></td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

For example: This renders as

```
<input name="color[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Color">
```

In the server side, this form on being submitted, gives a request.POST as below.

```
<QueryDict: {u'size[]': [u'asdasd', u'bla'], u'gender[]': [u'asdsda', u''], u'color[]': [u'adadas', u'67']>
```

Trying to access the array gives,

```
>> request.POST["color[]"]
>> u'67'
>> request.POST["size[]"]
>> u'bla'
```

Only the last value of the array is being returned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Drop the `[]` notation. That's from PHP or Rails and is unnecessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You need to use [`.getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to get the whole list instead.**

```
>>> request.POST.getlist("color[]")
[u'adadas', u'67']    
>>> request.POST.getlist("size[]")
[u'asdasd', u'bla']
```

Since `request.POST` is a [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects), it will return the last element on accessing a key having multiple values. You will have to use `.getlist` to get the complete value.

From [`QueryDict.__getitem__(key)` documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__)

> Returns the value for the given key. **If the key has more than one
>   value, `__getitem__()` returns the last value.**

For example:

```
>>> q = QueryDict('a=1', mutable=True) # create a querydict instance
>>> q.update({'a': '2'}) # add multiple value for key 'a'

>>> q['a'] # access a key having multiple values
['2'] # returns the last value

>>> q.getlist('a') # use getlist 
['1', '2'] # returns complete value
```